# python3: SIGPIPE missing from my signal lib

Tags: python, sigpipe

I have a program that previously used the following declaration at the top of it.

```
# no idea what this does but maybe it stops a SIGPIPE broken error from occuring.
from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_DFL)
```

The program deals with a long running IRC connection so I think this was necessary to prevent catastrophic errors occurring when attempting to write to a broken socket.

However I'm re-visiting the code now and my environment has changed slightly. I have python 3.4 installed and the script complains that SIGPIPE cannot be imported.

Sure enough when I look at the signal class I find that it no longer has a SIGPIPE member?

What gives, and how to I correct my code?

Comment: So if the problem is that you're trying to import signal.SIGPIPE but it doesn't work, then the problem is not reproduceable.

Comment: That is the point. I used to be able to do this because the code USED TO work but not it doesn't so if the library has changed then what do I do to change the code to get it to work?

Comment: Silly question, perhaps: does it help if you reorder the imports (i.e. write `from signal import SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL, signal`)?

Comment: No reordering doesn't help WING IDE does not appear to show .SIGPIPE as a member of signal library. So I am wondering if it has been removed from the library in this version of python 3.4 because it used to be there.

Comment: I'm going through the same problem. The code works well on Mac, but I'm getting same error on Windows